# Django Template rendering issue

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-templates

I am new to python, however I have fair idea of MVC from Java experience.
I have the following python code in my view

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

class MyListClass:
    def __init__(self, link, text):
        self.link = link
        self.text = text                

def index(request):
    list1 = MyListClass("hi","_hi_")
    list2 = MyListClass("hello","_hello_")
    bullets = [list1,list2]
    return HttpResponse(render_to_string("nest.html"), {"bullets": bullets})
```

And the below snippet in the HTML template

```
{% for bullet in bullets %}
<h2>
  <a href="{{ bullet.link }}">
    {{ bullet.text }}
  </a>
</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

But the values are not published in the html while other static texts are rendered from the HTML. 
According to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/), the object passed must be a dictonary.
Please let me know if I am going wrong somewhere.

Comment: I found the problem. In the python code the dictionary is passed to the wrong method.

Answer (score 2):

While your code should work (assuming you pass the context to the right method as you discovered), generally the `render` method is used instead of building an `HttpResponse` directly.

```
from django.shortcuts import render


def index(request):
    bullets = [
        MyListClass("hi", "_hi_"),
        MyListClass("hello", "_hello_")
    ]
    return render(request, "index.html", {"bullets": bullets})
```